# Split output data using CSV in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby

I have a csv file that has 7000+ records that I process/manipulate and export to a new csv file. I have no issues doing that and everything works as expected.

I would like to change the process to where it breaks the output into multiple files. So instead of writing all 7000+ rows to the new csv file it would write the first 1000 rows to newexport1.csv and the next 1000 rows to newexport2.csv until it reaches the end of the data.

Is there an easy way to do this with CSV in Ruby 1.9?

My current write method:

```
CSV.open("#{PATH_TO_EXPORT_FILE}/newexport.csv", "w+", :col_sep => '|', :headers => true) do |f|
export_rows.each do |row|
f << row
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no".  You'll want to adjust your current code to split up the set and then dump each subset to a different file.  This ought to be pretty close:

```
export_rows.each_slice(1000).with_index do |rows, idx|
  CSV.open("#{PATH_TO_EXPORT_FILE}/newexport-#{idx.to_s}.csv", "w+", :col_sep => '|', :headers => true) do |f|
    rows.each { |row| f << row }
  end
end
```

Comment: Pretty close? How about right on the money? This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should be able to replace `each_slice(1000).each_with_index` with `each_slice(1000).with_index`. That avoids enumerating the enumerator.

Comment: @theTinMan - changed - thanks for the suggestion. I didn't know about #with_index!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.
It's embedded in Ruby 1.9

[Check this link](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html)

To read:

```
CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
   # manipulate the content
end
```

To write:

```
CSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
   csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
   csv << ["another", "row"]
   # something else
end
```

I think that you'll need to combine one inside the other.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Which method/option should we be looking at?

Comment: @RodrigoOliveira I added my current write method to my original question. Export_rows is a hash of the manipulated data. That works fine for putting it in one file. What Im not sure of is how to get 1000 rows into newexport1.csv and the next 1000 rows into newexport2.csv. Will I need to have multiple write methods to change the file name (CSV.open("path/to/file.csv") or can I generate the file name dynamically?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can increment a variable when the number of lines is bigger than 1000, 2000. You can use a modulo function for that.

Answer (score 0):

FasterCSV is the standard CSV library since ruby 1.9, you can find a lot of example code in the examples folder:
https://github.com/JEG2/faster_csv/tree/master/examples

For the example code to work, you should change:

```
require "faster_csv"
```

for

```
require "csv"
```